# How to Loop Through Dataset one Row/Observation at a time

Tags: sas

I have a DataSet that I created with

```
filename tmp pipe 'dir "C:\Temp1\*.txt*" /b /s';

data Full;
    infile tmp dlm="\";
    length Path $2000 Path2 $2000 Path3 $2000 Path4 $2000 FileName $2000;
    input Path Path2 Path3 Path4 FileName;
run;
```

the Results look like:

```
C:\Temp1\test - Copy (12).txt
C:\Temp1\test - Copy.txt
C:\Temp1\test.txt
C:\Temp1\test - Copy (2).txt
C:\Temp1\test - Copy (3).txt
C:\Temp1\test - Copy (4).txt
C:\Temp1\test - Copy (5).txt
C:\Temp1\test - Copy (6).txt
C:\Temp1\test - Copy (7).txt
C:\Temp1\test - Copy (8).txt
C:\Temp1\test - Copy (9).txt
C:\Temp1\test - Copy (10).txt
C:\Temp1\test - Copy (11).txt
```

I am using the Code Below

```
options noxwait;
    data _null_;
    set Full nobs=nobs;
    i = 1;
    do while (i < nobs);
    set Full point=i;
    %let oldfile = <<<THIS IS WHERE I WANT THE DATA TO BE PULLED TO>>>;
    %let newfile = C:\Temp2\;
      rc= system("move &oldfile &newfile ");
      i = i + 1;
    put rc=;
    end;
    run;
```

basically I want to loop through my "Full" data set and put each row set to oldfile.

what do I need to fix in my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DATA` step is already an **implicit** loop over all the rows in the data set. You do not need to have other external agency controlling that.  Also, if just starting out, try not to mix data step scope and macro scope variables.

untested example:

```
data Full;
    infile tmp;
    input; * read whole line into _infile_ buffer;
    filename = _infile_; * transfer buffer to variable;
run;

data _null_;
  set full;
  command = "move " || quote(trim(filename)) || " " || quote(trim("C:\Temp2\"));
  rc = system(command);
run;
```